# Mongodb: promote sub-document to the top level

Tags: mongodb

I have document like this,

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "attribute1":"123",
  "attribute2":"abc",
  "subDocument": [
    {
      "attribute1":"456",
      "attribute2":"xyz",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to promote the first item of `subDocument` to the top level.
Note that the item of subDocument has the same attributes as in the top level and I want to replace them. So the result will be

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "attribute1":"456",
  "attribute2":"xyz",
  
}
```

How should I write the query? Playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/x0pzzwdi5k9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- get first member
- merge it with the root, and replace the root
- same names will be replaced from the first member

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251c0faf7e3c64c6511e177)

```js
update({},
[{"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$mergeObjects": 
       ["$$ROOT", {"$arrayElemAt": ["$subDocument", 0]}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["subDocument"]}])
```